# How to serve template based on collection handle (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a number of different collection templates. They differ in the filters that they contain. Some have three filter dropdowns, some only have one.

I would like to display different templates based on the collection type (handle). I know that you can manually change template in the admin, but I want to handle this programmatically within Liquid so the client doesn't have to worry about toggling alternate templates.

I have had no luck in the documentation or Shopify community forums.

An example of the logic:

```
If collection.handle = handle-name,
Then use collection template X,
Else default collection template
```

Grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

For detailed information you may refer to Shopify documentation on [Creating Alternate Templates](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/store/create-alternate-templates) or a similar [blog post](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/shopify-alternate-templates) on Partners Blog.

These articles suggest creating files with particular collection handle, that can be selected manually. Since you do not want to do that and have specified that only filters change based on different collections, so instead of replacing the whole template you can simply include the different snippet or section based on collection handle.

Example, inside collection.liquid

```
{% if collection.handle == 'collection-1' %}
  {% section 'collection-filters-1' %}
{% elsif collection.handle == 'collection-2' %}
  {% section 'collection-filters-2' %}
{% else %}
  {% section 'collection-filters-default' %}
{% endif %}
```